# Crontab jobs doesn't run multiple Scrapy spider properly

Tags: linux, cron, scrapy

I have a crontab job that runs a *myautorun.sh* file which contains 3 spider:

crontab -e

```
14 * * * * * ~bin/myautorun.sh
```

and myautorun.sh looks like this:

```
scrapy crawl spider1 &
scrapy crawl spider2 &
scrapy crawl spider3
```

each spider scrapes 20 pages.

when cronjob runs it ends up with variable scraped pages around 30, and never is 60. 
Each spider reads few pages but not all 20 pages. However if I comment two spiders and run them separately one at a time, it gives me 60.

So I am puzzled why it cant run parallel spiders properly,
I am running the spiders using Crawlera, and they are on a 1GB ram virtual server.

Is there any settings or anything that I am missing?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&` means you are running them in parallel, so that maybe was issue, your spiders were taking too much RAM and hence were being KILLED

Anyways, you should also redirect spider's outputs to logs files so in future there is any error, you will be able to see what has happened

```
scrapy crawl spider1 > logs_1.txt &
scrapy crawl spider2 > logs_2.txt &
scrapy crawl spider3 > logs_3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I created another virtual server with 3GB ram and it resolved the issue!